# Is it possible to directly access the radio signals on iOS or Android phones?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am interested in directly accessing the radio signal input/output in iOS or Android phone devices.  This could be the WiFi and/or the cellular radio signal.  I want to get at the digital equivalent of a digital oscilloscope trace of what radio signal going out of the phone and what radio signal is being received by the phone.
Ultimately, a phone transmits and receives radio signals, and then a lot of signal processing is done to those signals to turn them into useful information like digital data / GSM data, etc.

What is the best way using software running on the device to directly access the radio signal that is transmitted out of the device (the raw radio signal waveform) or the radio signal that is received by the device (the raw radio signal waveform)?

I'd like to:

1. Directly access the output radio signal.
2. Directly access the input radio signal.
   This would be the raw signal intensity, e.g. in samples vs. time at a high sampling rate (kHz/MHz).  This would basically be the equivalent of what a digitally-recording oscilloscope attached to a radio frequency antenna would receive while sitting next to the phone itself.

Comment: I don't think it can be done unless you use an external digital oscilloscope (and that is not what you want to do obviously). These integrated chip sets don't really have hooks that you can get to.

Comment: I am not sure about android but in iOS your access to the actual hardware input and output in negligible so i dont think its possible.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, I am going to call Apple about it, will let you know what I hear from them.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am working on a project along the same lines and looking for where to start? If the android and iOS systems don't allow access, how do you supervene these limitations to directly access the hardware?