# How to get instantaneous Voltage transmitted/received on GSM in Android?

Tags: android, signal-processing, gsm

Is it possible to get the instantaneous voltage transmitted or received on android code?

I wish to develop an app that would give a real time graph of the signal it transmits/receives  which would be useful for my research.

Is it possible?

PS- I can root my phone if needed.

Comment: Does this help? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately not. It only gives the strength of the signal link.I want the actual signal that is transmitted/received.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085671/is-it-possible-to-directly-access-the-radio-signals-on-ios-or-android-phones